# What does the word "Baked" mean when describing code?

Tags: php

Something I've never understood is why do people refer to code as being "Baked"?  For example on the [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) home page the term "A Fully Baked PHP Framework" is used and its something I see quite often.  Does the word "baked" have any meaning behind it?

Comment: Perhaps [half baked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_Baked) is the origin of this pun. And obviously any other earlier source for the term `half baked` meaning something poorly designed and/or executed.

Comment: CakePHP has a `bake` command to `bake` your `cake` meaning it helps you generate boilerplate code or install schema to a DB etc.. This is a more direct pun addressing the name of the framework.

Comment: I wrote some of my best code while I was baked. :)

Comment: @PeteR how outrageous! I shall research you and notify all your employers and clients. On second thought, got any baking powder left?

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Trust me, they already know!

Comment: Fully baked, means fully done - aka ready for 'consumption' (eating)

Comment: How about that baking powder then?

Answer (score 1):

This probably belongs on a different site (there's an English Usage Stack Exchange site I think?), but since it's bubbled to the top...

The word "baked" has a lot of meanings and uses, several of which can provide useful metaphors for aspects of programming:

- baking involves combining ingredients, following a recipe, and ending up with something more than the sum of its parts
- when you bake something in an oven, you first finish preparing the raw mixture; when your source code is ready to compile, it is ready to bake
- once something is "baked in", it is hard or impossible to change it, since baking is not reversible
- "half-baked" means an idea that is not fully thought through; "fully baked" therefore implies the contrary
- "a piece of cake" means "extremely easy", which is the likely inspiration for the name CakePHP, which I believe was first developed when "Ruby on Rails" was the hip new thing

The sentence you cite is drawing on several of these meanings to make a good soundbite; the implication is that other frameworks can't live up to them, and it's probably no coincidence that one of those rivals is CakePHP.